# Find integral $\int|z|dz$ on given path. Semicircle $|z|=1, -\frac{\pi}{2}\leq\arg z \leq \frac{\pi}{2}$

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis

Find integral $\int|z|dz$ on given path(starting from $z=-i$).

Semicircle $|z|=1,\,-\frac{\pi}{2}\leq\arg z \leq \frac{\pi}{2}$

My work.

$z=e^{it},\,x=\cos t,\,y=\sin t,\,dz=ie^{it}$

$\int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}ie^{it}dt = i(\frac{e^{i\pi/2}-e^{-i\pi/2}}{i})=2$

But answer in my book is $2i$. Where is the problem?

Comment: Your integral looks correct, I get $2i$ when I compute it. Can you show the steps you took to finish from there?

Comment: @StephenDonovan Added steps

Comment: Okay, again I agree with you up until the last step: $e^{i \pi / 2} = \cos(\frac\pi 2) + i \sin(\frac \pi 2) = i,$ right?

Comment: @StephenDonovan Ah My God. Thanks))

Answer (score 1):

The slightly easier way to do this would be by Cauchy, $$\int_{\text{semi-circle}} dz+\int_{i\rightarrow-i}dz=0$$ since the constant function $1$ is analytic. Hence the result would be just $$\int_{\text{semi-circle}} dz = \int_{-i\rightarrow i}dz=2i$$

Comment: Will be back to this answer when I'll learn Cauchy theorem. Thank you!